# Android development on Eclipse + Win XP - Autocomplete syntax hangs

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-xp

I switched from a Mac to my PC because Eclipse on a Mac was killing me. Windows definitely is much better, but eclipse hangs for 5-6 seconds everytime I try to make it autocomplete my syntax. Say when I hit imgView. and wait for it to pull up an image view properties, it just hangs for 5 seconds and then pulls them up.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Same for me on Ubuntu 10.04 64bit with Eclipse Helios. Which eclipse version are you using? I can't remember having this problem with Galileo.

Comment: Same here, this appeared only after upgrading to Helios (from Galileo). And on my (WinXP) computer the freeze is more like 10s, especially when loading completions from a View subclass.

Comment: This appears to be related to the Helios release of eclipse. I got so fed up with the hanging (on a quad-core i7 xeon it still freezes for 5-20seconds win/ubuntu) that I reverted to an older version of eclipse and there are no hangups although you sacrifice some nice new features of the IDE.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using Helios too. Any chance of removing a few auto complete categories to make it quicker? It can't take _that_ long if it's just method names ..

Answer (score 1):

Its a known Eclipse and JDK bug. 
Please see
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=548912&
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=171988&start=0&

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is:

1. Download `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+archive/<branch>.tar.gz` where `<branch>` is one of those listed here (froyo-release for 2.2, the file is about 113MB):
   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+refs
2. Extract the contents of base/ in the tar into "/platforms/android-/sources" where  is 8 for froyo, 7 for eclair, etc.
3. Enjoy fast content assist in 3.6!